# UITableviewcell loading data issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I parsed the XML data from a feed. I stored all data in `NSArray`. I loaded the images and title in `UITableview` using `UILable`. But when I use the scroll, the text will be collapsed as follows.

[image]

My code is as follows...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }           
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(70.0, 00.0, 250.0, 55);
    valueField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [valueField setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    valueField.tag = 111;
    valueField.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];
    valueField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    valueField.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    valueField.numberOfLines = 0;
    valueField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    valueField.text=[title1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    valueField.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    valueField.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
    valueField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    valueField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:valueField];
    [valueField release];
    UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"];
    UIView *backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: patternImage];
    cell.backgroundView = backView;
    NSString *image1 =[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Images  .....   = %@",image1);
    NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata];
    UIImageView *imageView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage: myimage ];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 00.0f, 60.0f, 63.0f); 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    //cell.imageView.image = myimage;
    return cell;
}
```

I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the cell is reloaded, the UILabel is added.

Do something like

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(70.0, 00.0, 250.0, 55);
    valueField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [valueField setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    valueField.tag = 111;
    valueField.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];
    valueField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    valueField.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    valueField.numberOfLines = 0;
    valueField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    valueField.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    valueField.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
    valueField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    valueField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:valueField];
    [valueField release];
}
valueField.text=[title1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your kindly reply. It working good. My problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, since you are dequeuing cells, when you call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it potentially can return you a cell that was already created.

That cell already has a label created.

So all of the magic of creating and setting up the custom views in you cell should only be done when `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns a `nil` value